# mongoose/mongodb .populate - nested document arrays & querying

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to do a `mongodb` `.populate` query on my `Users schema` to retrieve a list of `documents` of `events` that the user is attending. I have two `Mongodb` Schemas.

I have tried a number of things including:

```
Users.findById(req.params.id) 
  .populate('ticketsBought') // will return all event documents referenced in this ticketsBought Array 
  .exec(function (err, results) { 
      if (err) throw err; res.json(results); 
   });
```

and my own version of this which I have since deleted:

```
var schema = new Schema({
    name: String
  , em: [{ arr: [{ person: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Person'}}] }]
});
A.findById(id).populate('em.arr.person').exec(function (err, doc) {
  console.log(doc.em[0].arr[0].person instanceof mongoose.Document) // true
})
```

**Users** have:

```
ticketsBought: {
    type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    ref: 'Events',
    default: []
},
```

and **Events** have:

```
attending: {        
    type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    ref: 'Users'
},
```

I have tried every example of `populate` here https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/wiki/3.6-Release-Notes#added-documentpopulatedpath and all I am getting is an empty array or an array of mongo `ObjectId`'s.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: everything related to .populate in the mongoose wiki here: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/wiki/3.6-Release-Notes#added-documentpopulatedpath - I think maybe I am not using Ref's and names right in the code. I just want a simple something like this: Users.findById(req.params.id)  
   .populate('ticketsBought') // will return all event documents referenced in this ticketsBought Array   
   .exec(function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json(results);
   });

Comment: I just want you to edit the question and add exactly what you wrote in your code. I can't go through all the methods in that git repo. Nor anyone else will.

Comment: sorry I deleted most of the things I tried that didn't work as I went through them, I'll post them next time. I edited it and put in two of the things I tried.